# Rails: method `scoped' for Model:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :threads
end

class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :posts
end
```

In my view, I try this:

```
<%= @forum.name %>
<% @forum.threads.each do |thread| %>
  <%= link_to thread.name, [@forum, thread], :class => "remote" %>
<% end %>
```

And I get this error on line #1:

```
undefined method `scoped' for Thread:Class
```

Any idea what's going on here? I've seen other users describe this problem, but it's typically because they've pluralized the has_many or singularized the belongs_to. As far as I can tell, my models are well-made. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

The full stack trace:

```
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:123:in `target_scope'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:87:in `scoped'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:382:in `find_target'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:335:in `load_target'
C:in `load_target'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:87:in `method_missing'
app/views/forums/_show.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_forums__show_html_erb___1062139204_27502608'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/forums/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_forums_show_html_erb___608144578_36161352'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__271720943__process_action__435225614__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__598850227__call__514831618__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: could you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: I've added the stack trace.

Comment: thanks! is _show.html.erb:2 the `link_to` call?

Comment: It's actually the line before that. The real line 1 is "<%= @forum.name %>". I've added the full view for clarity's sake.

Comment: the erb you posted, is it `show.html.erb` or `_show.html.erb`? the error happens in the partial.

Comment: The erb is a partial. The actual show.html.erb is just '<%= render "/forum/show" %>'. I do it this way because I also have a show.js.erb file that uses the show partial to render this content with AJAX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by your model class name `Thread`, because it is also the name of a standard Ruby class.

When Rails tries to find the target class of the association it uses the internal class [`Thread`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html) (which has no `scoped` method) instead of your model class.

There a two solutions:

1. **Rename the model** (*best solution*)

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base #Thread class
end

class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
end
```

This way you can still keep your original association names:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :theads, class_name: 'Topic'
end
```

2. **Put your `Thread` model in a module** (*works but might have unwanted side-effects*)

```
class MyApp::Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :threads, class_name: 'MyApp::Thread'
end
```

You could also put *all* your models and controllers in a module. Rails looks for constants in the current module first, so your `Thread` class will be found first. This also has the advantage that you don't have to explicitly specify the `class_name` on your associations or in your controller actions.

```
class MyApp::Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class MyApp::Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :threads # Works!
end

class MyApp::ThreadsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @thread = Thread.find(params[:id]) # Works!
  end
end
```

But you also have to change your `routes.rb` to account for the module and your input names in your views will all be prefixed with the module name, so even if this solution looks very clean, it might not be what you want.

Comment: Excellent. Changed the Thread class name to ForumTopic and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this construct: `[@forum, thread]` is making rails look for a nested resource in config/routes.rb such as

```
resources :forums do
    resources :threads
end
```